# AngularJS input text depending on select

Tags: angularjs

I have one select in my AngularJS form. Depending on selected option I need to have different validation rules on input text element. What is the simplest way to implement this?

Comment: For example, there are two select options: % and $. Rules for input depending on selected option: % - Decimal with 3 decimal places
$ - Currency with no decimal places

Answer (score 0):

What about having different templates with the different validation rules written on the inputs?
As in the documentation for [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) the use the example of a select that change the view included

Comment: So if there is 10 select options I need to create 10 templates with input rules integrated? Is there something better?

Comment: Well you need to declare the validation rules as long as are different. Other possibility is to have ten objects with the validation rules and change then when the selects change.<input type="text" name="lastName" ng-model="user.last"
      ng-minlength="{{validator.minLength}}" ng-maxlength="{{validator.maxLength}}">